# Find hcaptcha callback function

Tags: python, callback, discord, captcha, 2captcha

I'm trying to solve hcaptcha nd I am able to get the key, however I cannot submit the button as it is invisible. I've looked at the javascript of the website but it's highly obfuscated and I cannot seem to find the callback to execute my h-captcha-response data. I've tried many things, such as creating a new widget and using hcaptcha.execute("widget_id") and tried creating my own submit button, but I've had no luck. Has anyone figured out how to submit the callback of invisible hcaptchas?

The website I'm trying to find the callback function for is https://discord.com/register

Comment: Hi blueey, did you manage to locate the callback function for the discord hcaptcha?
I've managed to get the bypass token, but not sure how to submit it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you solved this issue yet but from my understanding working with hcaptcha responses is that you are looking for a bypass token in your response to solve invisible captchas. I'm not sure how you're creating your requests but the way I'm able to get the bypass token is by including the HSW version in your request. An example response I've gotten looks like this:

```json
{
  c: {
    type: 'hsw',
    req: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoyLCJ0IjoidyIsImQiOiI1MTgyOTY0Mi0yY2RhLTRiMDktODk2Yy01OTRmODlkNzAwY2MiLCJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hc3NldHMuaGNhcHRjaGEuY29tL2MvMGY3NTU1OGQiLCJlIjoxNjE1ODE4ODg3fQ.G2J9qzif8nFNek9tlN1ouw3kDZU3i4zqaQvggO33dUo'
  },
  challenge_uri: 'https://hcaptcha.com/challenge/grid/challenge.js',
  key: 'e73e06e5-d305-4417-8c74-5a8434905bfa',
  request_config: {
    version: 0,
    shape_type: null,
    min_points: null,
    max_points: null,
    min_shapes_per_image: null,
    max_shapes_per_image: null,
    restrict_to_coords: null,
    minimum_selection_area_per_shape: null,
    multiple_choice_max_choices: 1,
    multiple_choice_min_choices: 1
  },
  request_type: 'image_label_binary',
  requester_question: { en: 'Please click each image containing a boat' },
  requester_question_example: [
    'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/27/SlmTCy7Lz4LCAjahpQA54SfVboig/6fDwZgoCAA6zpWjRVRFLLrlmxSwhw3I4vheI7G5EsEhOiH1iNBU90vekFjfYtbdvi7hYehYV3w8fL1e+0GXsvhf9jg==rnAfShy+KprfU9l4',
    'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/aF61+Uvq8hb+/bEdex6Gw/R7xvQS8bZlgHjQSCT52s9pMA95zTMcPlaMmu44MxBk+dWtvdpvWn7J6iQPhki9XWFfv5wgQbW6cMbpubFu5x5CQRJ6JVk0AETxZQ==FWODtehyavCQPCEu',
    'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/d1WlCaCp7S/Jv7zyer6CGHHqDNXSLgrryePvx+zeA4SNjKIjTGj+G+qduezfsOpE7DOYGkK8yc9TVxYZhR1eX01Y1mHHV7udskSomDZGL+QeV1iCA5ilZfnPRqcLyMUSyq9WhKBB'
  ],
  tasklist: [
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/PEgweRKSKDJ9Jsb45VOiWrK+AD6ZlKtBQpEWpl2f8s1QTYHhcKirVd0Zvuga0t5iyYBTwiNP/j38Ealhfe+Wrp2UJhvfzvS5kRVSjCgphd3RjuoouIWI/gyreTq5+9Qr4hS14tqOZJu1ZqdVe5h9mIu3Z3/CQ3iLToOjPl5apxF6PPCX4Yka6ieNP9alkRKLLxQxZteqP1DK4V5PVTZp',
      task_key: 'dd5bc33d-923b-4f43-8423-4916e7d6ed6b'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/qmIIDmNL60vS/i8nzkS7FSXCcHybuLy5o9G+iqgsQZ1vAf65rQTRWiwzXUgr+ZgW4km8Pbmtp4yMGtIYjghQoT3bDAqnjDgWAnGmY7FRuT3/4ZghK4fks1ck1PQlp94huMh9rlguKZpU5W8GILl4zdY7mOPuO4aDDRb5vHaBcFfpYuNHKHlya5d3Qr9dWRSqLOx/ChvrZrchz8UOQrjm',
      task_key: 'ddbbd309-dc94-4d1a-bfb1-a448d7418a15'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/3tuDvaYNlxEUiP2ca2gMbXZ6CuZVVxKrBw395ekJIGZO5JDzgoSNBMeVvdnbJY+rwCsbxnoRWKYamf/kAz2KZmwCw5DKHzOt8cJ5C1DvydwxS7xKpgY/Lx9kja4tFmuUo63tzGP8ijcMthMy1L8d2D2m8g3MYjSgCPNvZfpgieqRoP3DFCiJmmdQCnFHUpPfnZARA4bBcyI6bGAZccMv',
      task_key: '595b5186-2efb-45f8-b7f0-a15c89b70f0a'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/br4eWv9ThWoFCARzzVByH30bbWRCp+kPJz5CXU3toLl1R6tdjOiSXAEbGyanzxhy19AVQbFD2KzqBsR3O2rCsWJwN4NqVfEgrIgdQGw15dfJZoxZYaBVIdOKK4m9eO3UFlb7GIve0Fmhwrjwb2aaTR0AL2mw6gD37fyg5CwKEPiSaia/WA808/CSbWVwDflrON0=SteNR1UzZcF+2mhS',
      task_key: 'a900f277-b8c6-4c81-a7ae-3254a55c32af'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/CTqkR6FyUJ5YfieNQvprIsozKUa+VRNfNMQ7wr2oMLlKAlWpbykOWB+2EJyrXaj8HIlbQMMOfqonKphB/gcTpNGqYaqKgqgbGFK3snVnjE6PKPOKZ7hLLmrqv3AKlZVJgltPIIANVNb4nnC6ws6TCIMIy3PPRv4jIjO0NXJpDiPKvHwK69O1ijAx86tzx41elkSOg3Vxdm2dQmIB1UA1',
      task_key: '7759204f-d94b-427b-89d6-2babd1e040d2'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/wehOa9egBxS6rvlTPpvcMD/NL6rr14y0klso4c1vNGo5XrMBRlAuiRIZazwoRYXQaCeFHk7zUG3aMZYKKc0LUVDC6esTYgxEn4DxWClF+Mogobfb9WjkW2yniEGtSTr0MGJo9nyy2lJ2aDJ0b7DQnA2qVFTpKhb8if7WasYC7Tam9xVIddo6aYIDUX2049b8Fy0LCqnAeCxxcCZ6PczD',
      task_key: '248eef61-ddc1-4ad1-9777-29c7f592a39b'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/0oenP4E3kfYdi61gBMKqATZOT1i+1UusLSvlRUZksEnJqpjdnaXzhzK4t8PS+oSo8vkXcQcYHgG5eoHLlnTfT92qb5iAzT4QrhxiAuYtstcGqj5PXVzl2LyOF5wL5npogaENTREXwSTXkOnVLZ8ZlVUiLFbR6+h9vmDg1r4Xx8hX7k4TenTRReuxqjRnwXa+B2M=t5S5zLqeMGRjyTjW',
      task_key: '93dffb80-f1f2-4bf6-bf85-0d7cde55b0cc'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/57c8WXlALONMDJ1dUXGb7/AD2uZybutSU0kMTMK/mXjRIMZLVHOVtUvf5UbTG2ODVhJ99e8gM7XUCrlSdZw0P5G2cVk2C5C5/S7e4jvxw3gUONjMnPHT5FhH1UPiXi5aGYZRfuzNOZqdznXSDTzGnLZNayMgQba5IrUh+KughRVa6dqJSA/jia5Dt/3PzcsHUG/GrhJN/NRi4X2a3ioz',
      task_key: '0c16663e-e7fd-47f9-90f2-fff9bf426974'
    },
    {
      datapoint_uri: 'https://imgs.hcaptcha.com/7TD28mrtWK1IUr4btDxTTC5hxc6O2/z5NsKZVx/3JKuFC38LMrAIaeAeNoJqKIr4eMTTvR7E2CFWIEarZsKg0SMgUCxUXRofHh+Z9YqnuRNQkzDLAwqESk2+LGpSRiyz76JbMD0O/IlDTti8325eHLq1MELyzVvAAn2hPx/qMUgep3zXHymvaTPdvQ9rMPd63cY/SzLUeyCflnFG8tES',
      task_key: '4fed70fd-2a46-4a94-ba47-774fd2b93337'
    }
  ],
  'bypass-message': 'No bypass_token found.'
}
```

As you can see my `'bypass-message': 'No bypass_token found.'` at the bottom shows there is no bypass token for this captcha (this is because this request wasn't for an invisible captcha. When you create the request with an invisible captcha, if you make the request correctly that is the token you are looking for though. Hopefully this helps and feel free to shoot back more questions if you need any more help.